# How to Test My Coding for Track Running Distance Function in android

Tags: java, android, testing, distance, tracking

I'm currently making a fitness app that can track the running distance. But how to test my coding are working or not except taking the phone and running outside. Is it has another way to test the coding?

Comment: how are you going about keeping track of the distance?

Comment: I'm going to make my starting point as my current location with start button. And my ending point will be my current location as well. Because my current location will be changing when i'm running. But my code every time fail. And it's raining everyday. I can't go out to test my app. So any other idea to test this function?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accurately test functionality like tracking running distance is to actually do it yourself or find someone else who will do it for you. Even if you had a way to simulate it, **what really matters is if it actually works as intended on a real device doing what it was designed to do**. This is the beautiful process that is testing.